# Zend Framework, routing configuration makes me crazy

Tags: zend-framework

Zend Framework reports: Missing "route" in options array. I really cannot figure out why!!!

Here is my routing configuration options:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
         'sbe1' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part',
            'route' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                )       
            ),
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => array(

                'everythings' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/everythings',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\SbeController',
                            'action' => 'searching-results',
                            'category' => 'everythings'
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),      
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```